# Powershell ParentContainsErrorRecordException on shell namespace

Tags: shell, powershell, unzip

I'm trying to write an unzip powershell script, but I'm running into issues with the `$shell.NameSpace()` function.

```
function unzip ($sourceFile, $destination){
    $shell = new-object -com shell.application
    $zip = $shell.NameSpace($sourceFile)
    foreach($item in $zip.items()){
        $shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item) #Error here
    }
}

unzip "$PWD\folder.zip" $PWD
```

When I run this, I get an error on the second `$shell.NameSpace()` call.

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\scriptDir\unzipScript.ps1:9 char:6
+         $shell.NameSpace($destination).copyhere($item)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

What I dont understand is why this is failing on the *second* call. Clearly `PWD` exists and is a directory based on the first parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shell.NameSpace takes a string. $PWD is a PathInfo object. You can use $pwd.Path instead.

```
unzip "$PWD\folder.zip" $PWD.Path
```

As an alternative you can use the .Net System.IO.Compression.ZipFile class. [Here is a sample](http://www.adminarsenal.com/admin-arsenal-blog/powershell-zip-up-files-using-.net-and-add-type).

Comment: @DavidGrinberg it is enclosed in quotes and cast as a string.

Comment: @Matt Strange, when I did `unzip "$PWD\folder.zip" "$PWD"` that didnt work either.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg unzip "$pwd\folder.zip" "$pwd" does work for me as well. I'm fairly sure this is because it is being evaluated to a string by the quotes. I would still recommend moving away from comobjects to .Net where possible.